# Popen fails to start a process when I call it from a python script that runs as a Linux service

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, popen

I have a script which on certain conditions calls Popen to create new process. If I run this script from the command line, then Popen creates a process. But if I run the same script as a linux systemd service, then script executes normally except Popen part which fails to start a process. Same Popen failure thing happens if I start this script from within Java application deployed and running in Tomcat

I've tried to mix arguments in Popen construct, but I feel that I am missing something about the whole idea behind linux processes relationships
Here is the code which executes perfectly if started from cmd terminal like this: "python3 myscript.py" and fails if run as systemd service( systemctl start myscript.service - config file ofcourse exists) Fails Popen part

Service config file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Some Service
After=multi-user.target
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/my_service.py
StandardInput=tty-force

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Python script my_service.py itself:

```
import socket, os, signal, psutil
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, DEVNULL

def find_free_port():
    s = socket.socket()
    # Bind to a free port provided by the host.
    s.bind(('', 0))
    return s.getsockname()[1]

HOST = '91.230.195.104'
PORT = 65440

lastProcess = None
currentPID = os.getpid()

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:

   s.bind((HOST, PORT))
   s.listen()

   while True:
       try:
           print('Waiting for new Connection..')

           conn, addr = s.accept()

           if lastProcess != None:
               current_process = psutil.Process(lastProcess.pid)
               children = current_process.children(recursive=True)
               for child in children:
                   if child.pid != currentPID:
                       os.kill(child.pid, signal.SIGKILL)

           print('\nConnected to: '+str(addr))

           port_sender = find_free_port()
           port_videolink = None

           while True:
               port_videolink = find_free_port()
               if port_sender != port_videolink:
                   break

           with conn:
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                print('DRONE ID: '+str(data.decode()))
                if data:
                    conn.sendall(bytes(str(port_sender)+':'+str(port_videolink), 'utf-8'))
                    lastProcess = Popen("python3 video_receiver.py --port_videolink="+str(port_videolink)+
                                                       " --port_sender="+str(port_sender), shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setpgrp, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
                    print("Videofeed port: "+str(port_videolink)+"\n")
       except Exception as e:
             print(str(e))
```

there are no error or warning, just video_receiver.py process never starts :-\

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve], including information how you installed that in systemd. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: as you say, service fails. Please add for us log from your service. (journalctl -u <service> like I remember...
Also when you run Popen, it would be better when you use list with arguments. Include also stdout and stderr with subprocess.PIPE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the CWD for the process is different. To debug this have your program log the result of `os.getcwd()`. Another common issue although not the one occurring here is that PATH is different.

```
lastProcess = Popen("python3 video_receiver.py")
```

fails because `os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "video_receiver.py")) == False`

One solution is to provide the full paths to python and your script in the Popen call. The path to Python is only needed if you have Python installed in a virtual environment.

Another is to use `os.chdir()` or set the working directory in the service configuration.

Comment: Spot on!! Thank you very much, as you suggested, once I wrote the full paths - runs flawlessly. I will read more into this subject to deeper understand the reasons.