# Popen fails to start a process when I call it from a python script that runs as service in windows

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

My service calls subprocess.Popen(CMD) to start Everything when Everything not running. The commain line works well in windows shell or command, but not in service, is there something I missed?

I found another answer said it's a CWD problem in a similar question, don't
get it. [Popen fails to start a process when I call it from a python script that runs as a Linux service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57647539/popen-fails-to-start-a-process-when-i-call-it-from-a-python-script-that-runs-as)

```
class DetectorService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
_svc_name_ = "Detector"
_svc_display_name_ = "DetectorService"
_svc_description_ = "DetectorService"

def __init__(self, args):
    win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
    self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

def SvcStop(self):
    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

def SvcDoRun(self):
    rc = None
    while rc != win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        cmd = 'C:\\abspath\\Everything.exe -minimized -regex -close'
        subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=False,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
        rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, 1000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(DetectorService)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(DetectorService)
```

Comment: This sounds like some kind of Windows permissions problem to me, so not strictly related to python. Check that windows service account is allowed to create child process, and what settings/permissions is required for this operation.